# How can I compare columns from two csv files by key by Linux command line?

Tags: csv, awk, diff, cut

I have two CSV files:

hogehoge.csv

```
1,aaa,bbb
2,ccc,ddd
3,eee,fff
4,ggg,hhh
5,iii,jjj
6,kkk,lll
7,mmm,nnn
8,ooo,ppp
9,qqq,rrr
10,sss,ttt
```

hogehoge2.csv

```
1,aaa,bb
2,ccc,ddd
3,eee,fff
4,ggg,hhh
5,iii,jjj
7,mmm,nnn
8,ooo,ppp
9,qqq,rrr
10,sss,ttt
```

I want to get a result like this by command line (diff/cut/awk).

```
6,kkk,lll
```

There is a difference on 1st line, but I want to ignore this difference on 1st line.

Comment: this has been asked many times. What did you try so far?

Comment: diff hogehoge.csv hogehoge2.csv

awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] == 0' hogehoge.csv hogehoge2.csv

They are not collect.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is stated, you simply want to compare two files line-by-line.  `comm` may be a good choice:

```
comm -3 hogehoge.csv hogehoge2.csv
```

If you want to ignore the first line of each file:

```
comm -3 <(tail -n +2 hogehoge.csv) <(tail -n +2 hogehoge2.csv)
```

which will print exactly the output you specified.  Note: `comm -3` will print the lines that differ in each file, and the list of different lines in the second file will be indented with tabs.  To remove the tabs:

```
comm -3 <(tail -n +2 hogehoge.csv) <(tail -n +2 hogehoge2.csv) | sed $'s/\t*//'
```